# Why torus space we could see it in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, compact-manifolds

Anyone know why Torus we can see it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? 
I don't understand why torus as homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$ and see it in $\mathbb{R}^3$,   if  $ S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: The torus you see in $\mathbb R^3$ is homeomorphic to the one in $\mathbb R^4$. The one in $\mathbb R^4$ is very symmetric, whereas the one in $\mathbb R^3$ is distorted. In particular, the two $S^1$ factors play different roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can see $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, therefore, you can see $S^1\times S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. However, this doesn't mean it cannot be homeomorphic to a subspace of an euclidean space of lower dimension. Take for example the topological product of two straight lines ( both of which you can see as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$). The product is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself, so you don't need four, or even three dimensions.